# How to get accurate altitude using external sensor like BMP180,MPL3115A2

Tags: geolocation, altitude

I'm checking altitude data for every minute and stored in data logger,in this the value is not constant when I fix it on my desk for testing, so say no movement.
variation of value increases upto +- 20m difference. I use Reference pressure is 101.325 kPa (Sea Level).

Need Suggestion how to maintain accuracy standard as +- 0.2 meter as mentioned in sensor specification.

My data is

> date      &     altitude
>
> 11/19/2015 15:29  920.51
>
> 11/19/2015 15:30  920.51
>
> 11/19/2015 15:31  920.51
>
> 11/19/2015 15:32  920.42
>
> 11/19/2015 15:33  920.42
>
> 11/19/2015 15:34  919.783
>
> 11/19/2015 15:35  919.873
>
> 11/19/2015 15:36  919.691
>
> 11/19/2015 15:37  918.963
>
> 11/19/2015 15:38  919.418
>
> 11/19/2015 15:39  919.327
>
> 11/19/2015 15:40  919.873
>
> 11/19/2015 15:41  919.236
>
> 11/19/2015 15:42  919.145
>
> 11/19/2015 15:43  919.236
>
> 11/19/2015 15:44  918.69
>
> 11/19/2015 15:45  918.963
>
> 11/19/2015 15:46  919.236
>
> 11/19/2015 15:47  918.417
>
> 11/19/2015 15:48  919.145
>
> 11/19/2015 15:49  918.417
>
> 11/19/2015 15:50  918.872
>
> 11/19/2015 15:51  918.872
>
> 11/19/2015 15:52  918.781
>
> 11/19/2015 15:53  918.053
>
> 11/19/2015 15:54  918.872
>
> 11/19/2015 15:55  919.236
>
> 11/19/2015 15:56  919.327
>
> 11/19/2015 15:57  918.781
>
> 11/19/2015 15:58  919.054
>
> 11/19/2015 15:59  918.872
>
> 11/19/2015 16:00  919.145
>
> 11/19/2015 16:01  918.872
>
> 11/19/2015 16:02  918.508
>
> 11/19/2015 16:03  919.054
>
> 11/19/2015 16:04  919.054
>
> 11/19/2015 16:06  918.872
>
> 11/19/2015 16:05  918.144
>
> 11/19/2015 16:07  918.417
>
> 11/19/2015 16:08  919.236
>
> 11/19/2015 16:09  918.326
>
> 11/19/2015 16:10  918.235
>
> 11/19/2015 16:11  918.144
>
> 11/19/2015 16:12  918.417
>
> 11/19/2015 16:13  917.962
>
> 11/19/2015 16:14  917.143
>
> 11/19/2015 16:15  917.78
>
> 11/19/2015 16:16  917.962
>
> 11/19/2015 16:17  918.144
>
> 11/19/2015 16:18  917.871
>
> 11/19/2015 16:19  917.507
>
> 11/19/2015 16:20  917.78
>
> 11/19/2015 16:21  917.325
>
> 11/19/2015 16:22  917.234
>
> 11/19/2015 16:23  917.78
>
> 11/19/2015 16:24  916.688
>
> 11/19/2015 16:25  916.506
>
> 11/19/2015 16:26  916.597
>
> 11/19/2015 16:27  916.233
>
> 11/19/2015 16:28  915.96
>
> 11/19/2015 16:29  916.233
>
> 11/19/2015 16:30  916.142
>
> 11/19/2015 16:31  915.869
>
> 11/19/2015 16:32  915.778
>
> 11/19/2015 16:33  915.596
>
> 11/19/2015 16:34  916.233
>
> 11/19/2015 16:35  915.869
>
> 11/19/2015 16:36  915.687
>
> 11/19/2015 16:37  916.142
>
> 11/19/2015 16:38  915.869
>
> 11/19/2015 16:39  915.414
>
> 11/19/2015 16:40  915.687
>
> 11/19/2015 16:41  915.96
>
> 11/19/2015 16:42  915.323
>
> 11/19/2015 16:43  915.869
>
> 11/19/2015 16:44  914.868
>
> 11/19/2015 16:45  915.505
>
> 11/19/2015 16:46  915.05
>
> 11/19/2015 16:47  915.232
>
> 11/19/2015 16:48  915.05
>
> 11/19/2015 16:49  914.777
>
> 11/19/2015 16:50  915.414
>
> 11/19/2015 16:51  914.686
>
> 11/19/2015 16:52  914.596
>
> 11/19/2015 16:53  915.232
>
> 11/19/2015 16:54  914.868
>
> 11/19/2015 16:55  915.141
>
> 11/19/2015 16:56  915.141
>
> 11/19/2015 16:57  915.141
>
> 11/19/2015 16:58  915.323
>
> 11/19/2015 16:59  914.959
>
> 11/19/2015 17:00  914.322
>
> 11/19/2015 17:01  914.959
>
> 11/19/2015 17:02  914.777
>
> 11/19/2015 17:03  914.868
>
> 11/19/2015 17:04  914.777
>
> 11/19/2015 17:05  914.504
>
> 11/19/2015 17:06  914.231
>
> 11/19/2015 17:07  914.504
>
> 11/19/2015 17:08  914.414
>
> 11/19/2015 17:09  914.231
>
> 11/19/2015 17:10  914.231
>
> 11/19/2015 17:11  914.141
>
> 11/19/2015 17:12  914.141
>
> 11/19/2015 17:13  913.867
>
> 11/19/2015 17:14  914.596
>
> 11/19/2015 17:15  914.141
>
> 11/19/2015 17:16  913.867
>
> 11/19/2015 17:17  913.686
>
> 11/19/2015 17:18  913.231
>
> 11/19/2015 17:19  913.504
>
> 11/19/2015 17:20  913.867
>
> 11/19/2015 17:21  913.867
>
> 11/19/2015 17:22  913.594
>
> 11/19/2015 17:23  913.049
>
> 11/19/2015 17:24  912.321
>
> 11/19/2015 17:25  913.14
>
> 11/19/2015 17:26  912.049
>
> 11/19/2015 17:27  912.321
>
> 11/19/2015 17:28  911.503
>
> 11/19/2015 17:29  911.866
>
> 11/19/2015 17:30  911.503
>
> 11/19/2015 17:31  911.139
>
> 11/19/2015 17:32  910.593
>
> 11/19/2015 17:33  910.775
>
> 11/19/2015 17:34  910.411
>
> 11/19/2015 17:35  910.321
>
> 11/19/2015 17:36  909.956
>
> 11/19/2015 17:37  909.956
>
> 11/19/2015 17:38  910.048
>
> 11/19/2015 17:39  909.593
>
> 11/19/2015 17:40  908.138
>
> 11/19/2015 17:41  908.411
>
> 11/19/2015 17:42  907.956
>
> 11/19/2015 17:43  907.956
>
> 11/19/2015 17:44  908.138
>
> 11/19/2015 17:45  907.32
>
> 11/19/2015 17:46  908.229
>
> 11/19/2015 17:47  907.684
>
> 11/19/2015 17:48  907.502
>
> 11/19/2015 17:49  907.411
>
> 11/19/2015 17:50  906.774
>
> 11/19/2015 17:51  907.32
>
> 11/19/2015 17:52  907.411
>
> 11/19/2015 17:53  907.411
>
> 11/19/2015 17:54  907.138
>
> 11/19/2015 17:55  906.865
>
> 11/19/2015 17:56  906.593
>
> 11/19/2015 17:57  906.229
>
> 11/19/2015 17:58  905.683
>
> 11/19/2015 17:59  906.138
>
> 11/19/2015 18:00  905.047
>
> 11/19/2015 18:01  906.047
>
> 11/19/2015 18:02  905.138
>
> 11/19/2015 18:03  905.047
>
> 11/19/2015 18:04  904.684
>
> 11/19/2015 18:05  904.593
>
> 11/19/2015 18:06  904.32
>
> 11/19/2015 18:07  904.774
>
> 11/19/2015 18:08  904.411
>
> 11/19/2015 18:09  904.593
>
> 11/19/2015 18:10  904.593
>
> 11/19/2015 18:11  904.138
>
> 11/19/2015 18:12  904.956
>
> 11/19/2015 18:13  903.684
>
> 11/19/2015 18:14  903.957
>
> 11/19/2015 18:15  904.048
>
> 11/19/2015 18:17  904.048
>
> 11/19/2015 18:18  903.229
>
> 11/19/2015 18:19  903.229
>
> 11/19/2015 18:20  903.229
>
> 11/19/2015 18:21  903.139
>
> 11/19/2015 18:22  903.32
>
> 11/19/2015 18:23  902.684
>
> 11/19/2015 18:24  902.775
>
> 11/19/2015 18:25  902.957
>
> 11/19/2015 18:26  902.684
>
> 11/19/2015 18:27  903.048
>
> 11/19/2015 18:28  902.957
>
> 11/19/2015 18:29  902.139
>
> 11/19/2015 18:30  902.684
>
> 11/19/2015 18:31  902.684
>
> 11/19/2015 18:32  902.775
>
> 11/19/2015 18:33  902.593
>
> 11/19/2015 18:34  902.412
>
> 11/19/2015 18:38  902.866
>
> 11/19/2015 18:36  902.957
>
> 11/19/2015 18:37  902.957
>
> 11/19/2015 18:43  901.412
>
> 11/19/2015 18:40  902.321
>
> 11/19/2015 18:41  901.867
>
> 11/19/2015 18:42  901.776
>
> 11/19/2015 18:46  901.231
>
> 11/19/2015 18:45  901.867
>
> 11/19/2015 18:47  901.867
>
> 11/19/2015 18:48  901.231
>
> 11/19/2015 18:49  901.14
>
> 11/19/2015 18:50  900.776

Comment: That looks like just standard sort of weather changes...  20m altitude equivalent in 3 and a bit hours is the sort of thing you should expect from a pressure based system.  What to do about it depends on what you are trying to achieve.  The variance between sample points looks good.  If you had more I would say take more readings and average them.

Comment: i'm in need of attaining altitude accuracy constantly. if i want to average them how many readings has to be taken to average them say 10 values , or i have to compare and assign the value level like 900m to 905m as 901m, checking for a big change to show the value is like compromising accuracy level to say 5m difference, so instead of pressure based system which system is best, what are the other possibility to attain my goal.any suggestion @Ifor

Comment: What is the data for?  Collected as you move or stationary?  There are not any really accurate long term methods with a smart phone.  The best method would depend what you want the data for.  Other options are GPS but the base altitude is bad and there are systematic errors.  Using the gps lat / long co-ordinates and then doing an online lookup is often better but it depends on the quality of the data for the lookup and varies around the world.

Comment: i'm using altitude sensor in tower crane used in construction zone for ref:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crane_(machine)., sometimes it may be stationary i have tested with gps module accuracy is not good, so now i'm trying with sensor (BMP180,MPL3115A2)

Comment: I would presume your looking for relatively quick movements compared to the weather type drift.  Some form of high pass filtering may get you the information on when movement is occurring and it's relative amount.